# Are there any non-ISKCONic translations of the Chaitanya Charitamrita in English?

Tags: translation-request, book-recommendation, chaitanya

I would like to read a non-ISKCONic translations of the Chaitanya Charitamrita in English. Could anyone suggest me any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Edward C. Dimock has a written a complete English translation of the Chaitanya Charitamrita along with a nonsectarian commentary. However, its not available online. It is available for purchase on [Amazon.com].

[Caitanya Caritamrta of Krsnadasa Kaviraja: A Translation and Commentary (Harvard Oriental Series)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0674002857)